# Unable to set the path to bin, lib for selenium (maven) project for jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Trying to run selenium test cases. Which ever document i have seen, suggestion is to add path to bin and lib directory.

```
Set projectLocation=F:\Selenium\TestNGBatchExample
cd %projectLocation%
set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml
pause
```

But in maven project, there is no bin, lib folders in my maven project. Is there any mistake being done in exporting the projecting or any other place. Test cases run perfectly in local environment when executed from eclipse.

[image: project structure in local]

[image: Project structure on windows server]

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>automationtests360</groupId>
 <artifactId>s360test</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>page factory in simplify360</name>
 <description>page factory in simplify360</description>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
   <version>2.52.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.9.10</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
   <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
   <version>2.11.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.36</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.7</source>
     <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What you have added in your `pom.xml` to execute project ?

Comment: Testng is the framework used for executing the test cases. If i'm providing incorrect information, please explain me what info i should be looking at in pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute `testNg.xml` file via Maven, you can use surefire plugin. Add below lines in `plugins` > `configuration` section of your `pom.xml` file, if you have not already.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Getting this error while trying to build 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project s360test: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file D:\TestAutomation\s360Selenium_1\testng.xml is not a valid file

Comment: added the pom.xml file

Comment: it says the `testing.xml` file you have given is not a valid file. Does the file available at the given location ? Can you paste the file here please ?

Comment: no there is no file as such in my project. What is testng.xml file in the code given by you. Even i tried adding the testcases xml generated to execute the xml file, but still the same issue

Comment: Ohh..you need to specify a name of valid file name if you are executing it via TestNG.

Comment: So i don't need to provide the path to lib and bin right